# MongoDB - Sort by index of array

Tags: mongodb

I have an array `idsToHunt` - this contains x number of IDs.

I'm using this is an aggregate like:

```
Question.aggregate([
          {$match: {publicID: { $in: idsToHunt} },
          {$project: {_id:0, publicID:1, score:1} },
          {$sort: {score: -1}}
          ],
          function(err, found) {
            nextStep = found
            resolve();
          })
```

Now where I have `{$sort: {score: -1}}` - what i really want to do is sort by the index of `idsToHunt`.

So if `idsToHunt = ['da22', 'ye66', '17hy']`

Then I'd like the projected results to be like:

`{publicID: 'da22', score: '2'}, {publicID: 'ye66', score: '2'}, {publicID: '17hy', score: '2'}`

rather than a random order as it is now:

`{publicID: 'da22', score: '2'}, {publicID: '17hy', score: '2'}, {publicID: 'ye66', score: '2'}`

Hope that makes sense - any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I see that answer - and I realise that `$in` doesn't follow a strict order however I'm still unclear how to solve?

Comment: The answers to the question tell you your options regarding how to solve it. There's no easy way.